# sticky element not moveing when horizontal scrollbar scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I have use stickyjs(http://stickyjs.com/) to stick div on top by I not wanted to stick div when I scroll the page to right-left.
we like to have div stick only when moving to the top to bottom.
here is the sample that I trying
 [jsfiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/zaazhp2d/524/)

seeking some help.

Comment: From what I see https://jsfiddle.net/zaazhp2d/528/ it is sticking scrolling top and bottom only, BUT if you've scrolled down then scroll right it'll stick.

Comment: it's not working once you scroll down then if you move left right still it shows that stick div